# Is it possible to clear drawn particular square from the drafting screen in OpenGL ES 2.0?

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I am in the process of developing a drafting tool using OpenGL ES 2.0, I have made arrangement to draw lines & circles using a button click.  What I need presently is to indicate the edges of the line to snap so that another line can be drawn from the end of the line.  The snap should be indicated as a box which indicates that the edge is been selected and soon as another line or circle is made to draw from that edge, the box should disappear.  Can anyone help in clearing the particular box drawn in the drafting screen while the other lines are circles drawn using button click remain in the screen ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think anyone could help you with an right answer because it depends only on your code for rendering items. Just don't render the snap box if you don't want to.